# Atualizar determinado campo de uma tabela - SSMS V18

Tags: sql, sql-update, ssms

Estou preenchendo uma tabela com dados que pego em um JSON, conforme a imagem:
[image]

Quando o *markettype* é *'place'*, não tem a informação correta de *'category'* e *'distance'*. Quando o *markettype* é *'win'*, tem a informação correta. Eu queria preencher essas duas informações com os dados corretos, e tentei fazer alguns `update` comparando *'marketdate'* e *'idrunn'*, pra ter certeza que é o mesmo evento, e `marketype = 'win'`, pegar os dois valores que preciso e atualizar na linha *'place'*, mas não deu certo... A situação está muito complexa para meu pouco conhecimento.

Resumindo, seria pegar o *marketdate* e o *idrunn* da linha `marketype = 'win'` e comparar com as linhas `markettype = 'place'`. Quando o *marketdate* e o *idrunn* for iguais, significa que é o mesmo evento aí seria atualizar o campo *'category'* e *'distance'* da linha *'place'*.

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: e o que já tentou fazer? coloque a query na pergunta. Mas vai precisar fazer uma subquery para pegar o outro valor

Comment: Veja se ajuda (update com self-join) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2380353/update-with-self-join

Answer (score 0):

No caso um jeito facil pra você fazer isto é criando um cursor

tipo assim:

````
declare seuCursor cursor
    local for 
    --select atr1,atr2... from suatabela

declare 
    --@variaveis que for utilizar
    @atr1 varchar(200),
    @atr2 varchar(200);

open seuCursor
fetch next from seuCursor into @atr1,@atr2... --as variaveis, 
--lembrando que tem que ser de acordo com o select. se seu select é select nome, idade from suatabela seu into será into @nome, @idade
while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin
    --cria a sua logica
    --if(@variavel for igual a tal)
    --begin
        --update alguma coisa
    --end

    -- repete o fetch next from into
end
close seuCursor

DEALLOCATE seuCursor```
````